# insertar pdf en una base de datos en mysql

Tags: mysql, pdf

se puede ingresar un archivo pdf en una base de datos mysql y como seria el proceso, como que el dato fuera un archivo pdf, y como se tre en una consulta

Comment: No está claro lo que se está preguntando, además falta una breve descripción de los buscado/investigado.

Comment: Respuesta corta: Si, se puede almacenar un binario en la base de datos da igual el tipo de archivo. Para una respuesta larga y acorde al resto de la pregunta se require mas informacion y detallar que se quiere hacer exactamente, que estas usando y que has intentado hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal es que insertes solo la ruta de dicho archivo

Y el archivo lo guardes en una ruta de tu servidor.

```
$_FILES
```

De igual forma te dejo un ejemplo que encontre de como guardar el archivo en BD de forma binaria

[Guardar Imagen/PDF en Base de datos Binario](http://www.forosdelweb.com/f18/tutorial-ejemplo-subir-archivos-bd-guardando-bd-binario-127775/)